# HTTP/1.1 302 Found - in Android after httpPost

Tags: java, asp.net, android, http, httpclient

after executing post method on the server i get this error: HTTP/1.1 302 Found, which as i know states that there is a redirect that follows. I am trying to fill in the logon form and post it to server, after doing so, i get this redirect.

P.S. The form submit method is postback.. maybe this is a key?

P.P.S. After posting this:

```
__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&ctl00$tbUsername=qwerty&ctl00$tbPwd=qwerty&ctl00$chkRememberLogin=0&ctl00$cmdLogin=Login&ctl00$cmdForgetMe=Forget Me
```

I get this:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://website/mobile/(X(1)S(lyslolvcdq13af45juum2vel))/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fsyspower3%2fmobile%2fdefault.aspx&amp;AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Plus the set of headers:

```
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): Cache-Control
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): private
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): Content-Type
08-02 13:48:39.084: INFO/System.out(1853): text/html; charset=utf-8
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): Expires
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:48:33 GMT
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): Server
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): Microsoft-IIS/7.5
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): Set-Cookie
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): ASP.NET_SessionId=ebmsrf45wb3mcq45qrgrfe55; path=/; HttpOnly
08-02 13:48:39.093: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): X-AspNet-Version
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): 2.0.50727
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): X-Powered-By
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): ASP.NET
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): Date
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:48:33 GMT
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): ====Header=====
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): Content-Length
08-02 13:48:39.104: INFO/System.out(1853): 1272
```

**EDITED**:
Now i can see the new location that I must proceed to. But here is a new problem, when i enter this new link into the browser, i get into the server(i pass login), but if I do a new request(POST) to server, then i am being thrown back to the login page...

**P.S.** Now i am using **HttpURLConnection** for the post method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error. That's just an informal message that there's a redirect. Only HTTP 4nn and 5nn responses are real errors. The redirect URL is available in the HTTP `Location` header. You, as being a web client, are obligated to send a new GET request on the URL as specified in the HTTP `Location` header.

```
String location = response.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
// ...
```

---

**Update**: So, you got a HTTP 302 response without a `Location` header? What's the status code of the response itself?

```
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

If this is 200 and the body contains a 302 message, then it's definitely a bug in the server side. The webserver should have returned a status code of 302 along with a `Location` header.

---

**Update 2**: So, the status code is actually 200. That's a bug in the server side. If that website is not under your control and thus you cannot fix the server, then you need to report it to the admin/maintainer of the website. In the meanwhile, best what you could do is to extract the new location from the response body using some HTML parser and then send a new GET request on it. For example, using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org):

```
String location = Jsoup.parse(responseHtml).select("h2 a").first().attr("href");
// ...
```

Comment: ====Header=====
Cache-Control
private
====Header=====
Content-Type
text/html; charset=utf-8
====Header=====
Expires
Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:48:33 GMT
====Header=====
Server
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
====Header=====
Set-Cookie
ASP.NET_SessionId=ebmsrf45wb3mcq45qrgrfe55; path=/; HttpOnly
====Header=====
X-AspNet-Version
2.0.50727
====Header=====
X-Powered-By
ASP.NET
====Header=====
Date
Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:48:33 GMT
====Header=====
Content-Length
1272

Comment: here are the set of headers that i get

Comment: status code have returned 200.. Does it mean that the post request had gone through? And what kind of a bug may it be on the server side? I am zero in asp.net

Comment: Truly the POST was successful. Status codes of 2nn and 3nn are successful responses. 3nn just means that there's a change in the target location. If you got 4nn, then it means that your request was wrong (which is thus not the case). If you got 5nn, then it means that the server threw an exception (usually caused by bug in server code). You got response status code 200 with a response body of a 302. This is wrong. If the server side code is completely outside your control, then you need to report it to the maintainer of the website.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will go through the code, maybe i have made some mistakes, gonna check it. Otherwise I have no idea..

Comment: Now i can see the new location that I must proceed to. But here is a new problem, when i enter this new link into the browser, i get into the server(i pass login), but if I do a new request(POST) to server, then i am being thrown back to the login page...

P.S. Now i am using HttpURLConnection for the post method

Comment: You need to send the obtained session cookie back in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

The code `302` is not considered an error. It is an instruction to the client that it should continue on to the location specified by the `Location` response header. The client should follow that directive and proceed to the indicated location.

Since this server isn't returning `Location`, it looks like you will have to parse the response body and follow the URL specified there.

Comment: Location is not specified, i printed out all the headers